# How to change font color in PDF based by font name Perl

Tags: perl

I have pdf with 8 to 9 font. I want to change the font color for each fonts. Is there any possibilities in perl

Code:

```
 use PDF::Reuse; 
 use strict; 

 my $n = 1; 
 prFile('1577-2 Provigil P1_out.pdf'); 
 while (1) { 
   prText(550, 40, $n++); 
   prSinglePage('1577-2 Provigil P1.pdf'); 
 }
 prEnd();
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a bit too old, but I was looking for this as well and thought of adding this for the sake of others. I found the answer from [this link](http://www.perladvent.org/2003/18th/) which provides many good examples.

You need to use `prAdd` to send direct postscript commands to change font colors.

```
prAdd("1.0 1.0 1.0 rg");   # white
```

Use this before you use `prText`.
Hope this helps others like me to find a solution for this common task.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible

Read [here about PDF Processing with Perl](http://www.perl.com/pub/2007/09/20/pdf-processing-with-perl.html) to get started

Comment: I have tryed but i am unable to change the font color in pdf. Can i get any examples on this. I am unable to fill the font color for existing pdf.